# Text position problems with UserAccountsDrawerHeader in the Drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a userAccountsDrawerHeader in the Drawer with a photo, username and email but I get a location or text positioning problem.

The text it shows is from the database using a future builder and it gives me a problem.

But when I test the properties of userAccountsDrawerHeader(accountName,accountEmail) using a Text widget with no data from the database, the text is located correctly, no problem there.

How can I solve that?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

code and image::

```
    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName:NombreCabeceraDrawer(),
     accountEmail:CorreoCabeceraDrawer(),
    ),
    
 class CorreoCabeceraDrawerextends StatefulWidget{return correocabeceradrawer ();}

    class correocabeceradrawer extends State<CorreoCabeceraDrawer>{
    
        Widget CorreoCabeceraDrawer(){
            return Container(
              child: Text(correousuario), ); }
        
        
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: futureServices,
                  builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
                    List  listainfocabeceradrawer = snapshot.data;
                    if(snapshot.hasData ) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: listainfocabeceradrawer.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context,i){
                                correousuario = listainfocabeceradrawer[i].CorreoUsuario;
                                return Container(
                                  child: CorreoCabeceraDrawer(),
                                  ); }), ),);
        
                    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    } return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    );
                  }
              ),
            );
            throw UnimplementedError();
          }}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PxY6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPT6L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPQpz.png)

Answer (score 0):

if we think simple is this code work with your code?

```
  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName:NombreCabeceraDrawer(),
     accountEmail:CorreoCabeceraDrawer(),
    ),
    
 class CorreoCabeceraDrawerextends StatefulWidget{return correocabeceradrawer ();}

    class correocabeceradrawer extends State<CorreoCabeceraDrawer>{
    
        Widget CorreoCabeceraDrawer(){
            return Container(margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:40),
              child: Text(correousuario), ); }
        
        
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: futureServices,
                  builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
                    List  listainfocabeceradrawer = snapshot.data;
                    if(snapshot.hasData ) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: listainfocabeceradrawer.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context,i){
                                correousuario = listainfocabeceradrawer[i].CorreoUsuario;
                                return Container(
                                  child: CorreoCabeceraDrawer(),
                                  ); }), ),);
        
                    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    } return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    );
                  }
              ),
            );
            throw UnimplementedError();
          }}
```

Comment: your answer helped me with accountEmail but not with accountName. There is an error in the design, the further down I make the text, it disappears.

I was testing and I realized that some part of the future builder I think is the problem.
If there is only one Text widget, there is no problem with any text

Comment: I just added another image.